# Centering <g> element after loading svg-pan-zoom.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've been working in panning and zooming with inline svg here: [www.jard.us](http://www.jard.us)

Here you have the whole structure of the current site: https://github.com/Reivajar/svg-pan-zoom-for-JARD2

I've got a relatively good implementation of the svg-pan-zoom library with the desired svg, but I have no idea why the  element used by the library to zoom and pan the svg is not completely centered, but slightly moved to the right. I've tried to readjust the horizontal alignment through CSS by using the class selector (.svg-pan-zoom_viewport) but nothing moves. Maybe I need to change something in the js but I've been checking it out and apparently everything is centered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the site http://www.jard.us which looks pretty cool by the way, it looks to me like your positioning of the svg graphic within the html is fine, but possibly the svg image has additional padding to the left. So it might help to edit the svg in an SVG editor, Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape and this should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks!
The same svg code without the svg-pan-zoom library [link](http://jard.es/demo012/) apparently fits well and has no padding. That's why I think it is caused by the library itself.